# Building Macro in Excel to count Cell value > 100 that dynamically keeps changing

Tags: excel, vba

Need help in creating a macro in Excel for cell vValue that remains dynamic (keeps changing due to streaming numbers).

If anytime the cell value is greater than 100 the adjacent cell should keep a check of how many times the cell value has been changed to greater than 100 and upon closing of the workbook the count should reset to 0, this is only of one cell and not a range of cells.

So far I have this from some other online resource but does not seem to work.

```vb
Dim xCount As Integer
 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target = Range("B9") Then
        xCount = xCount + 1
        Range("C9").Value = xCount
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set xRg = Application.Intersect(Target.Dependents, Me.Range("B9"))
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
        xCount = xCount + 1
        Range("C9").Value = xCount
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your worksheet code module:

```
Public BlnAboveHundred As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim RngTrigger As Range
    Dim RngMeasure As Range
    Dim RngCounter As Range
    
    Set RngTrigger = Range("B9,P9:T9,S10")
    Set RngMeasure = Range("B9")
    Set RngCounter = Range("C9")
    
    If Not (Intersect(Target, RngTrigger) Is Nothing) Then
        If RngMeasure.Value > 100 Then
            If BlnAboveHundred = False Then
                RngCounter.Value = RngCounter.Value + 1
                BlnAboveHundred = True
            End If
        Else
            BlnAboveHundred = False
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Put this in your workbook code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Dim StrString01 As String
    Dim RngCounter As Range
    
    Set RngCounter = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C9")
    
    StrString01 = RngCounter.Value
    
    RngCounter.Value = 0
    
    Select Case MsgBox("Do you want to save the changes you made to '" & Me.Name & "'?", vbYesNoCancel + vbExclamation + vbDefaultButton1, "Microsoft Excel")
        Case Is = 6
            Me.Save
        Case Is = 7
            Me.Saved = True
        Case Is = 2
            RngCounter.Value = StrString01
            Cancel = True
    End Select
    
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Me.Sheets("Sheet1").BlnAboveHundred = Me.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9") > 100
    
End Sub
```

Change the sheet name from `Sheet1` to the name of your sheet. If you need it, change also the text in the MsgBox from english to your own language.

---

### **EDIT: New codes according to comments**

Put this in a new module:

```
Declare Function APIBeep Lib "kernel32" Alias _
                 "Beep" (ByVal dwFreq As Long, ByVal dwDuration As Long) _
                 As Long


Function FunCounter(RngMeasure As Range)
    
    If RngMeasure.Value > 100 Then
        If BlnAboveHundred = False Then
            IntCounter = IntCounter + 1
            APIBeep 1000, 200
            BlnAboveHundred = True
        End If
    Else
        BlnAboveHundred = False
    End If
    
    FunCounter = IntCounter
    
End Function
```

Put this in your workbook code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    BlnAboveHundred = Me.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("T9") > 100
    IntCounter = 0
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Formula = "=FunCounter(T9)"
    
End Sub
```

Change the sheet name from `Sheet1` to the name of your sheet. In the cell B9 of your sheet write the formula `=FunCounter(T9)`.

Comment: Thanks, I am very close at this point, But still the Counter keeps increasing by 1 if the value of Cell is 101.102.103..., What is want is, if the Value is 100 or keep going above the Counter should stop unless the value falls less than 99 and then comes back to 100, counter should be 2.

Comment: Ok, that's a little different. What if the value in B9 is above 100 when the file is closed and saved? Once the file is opened the counter should be 1 or 0? And what if the value in B9 stays always above 100?

Comment: I've edited the code. Right now if the value in B9 is above 100 when the file is closed (and saved), the counter is reset to 0 and it will step to 1 after the value in B9 goes below and one time above 100. I've also changed the workbook code so that it will be activated even if the user has just saved the file.

Comment: Thanks @Evil Blue Monkey, this seems to be working great, however like i mentioned that this is live number streaming, B9 at the opening of work book will always have some number, now at the beginning, the code checks for nothing, so the code simply does not start due to that condition and counter does not start because of B9 being populated. Please could you change it for me. Rest all is good.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you have written. The private subroutine `Worksheet_Change` will activate itself when a cell value is changed. So as long as the value in B9 will be changed, the private subroutine will react to that; i doesn't matter whether the cell is populated or not. It won't activate itself in case B9 contains a formula, because in such case only a change in the formula itself would trigger the private sub; the changes in the formula outcome won't. If that's the case, i need to know more about this formula and find an event that will be linked to the change of its outcome.

Comment: B9 does contain a simple formula of adding of 2 cells formula =SUM(S9:S10)*25

Comment: Whenever the sum of these CELLS *25 cross 100 the counter CELL should increase by 1

Comment: Do cells S9 and S10 also contain formulas? Or are their values changed manually or via macro?

Comment: Yes unfortunately S9 also has a formula S9=(R9-Q9)

Comment: Ok, let's cut it to the point: following each reference at what point the data is entered via macro or manually? At some point there will have to be a change made.

Comment: Data Live Streamed in Cells (Keeps changing every second): P9, Q9 & Data Entered Manually: R9 & Formula in S9: =(R9-Q9) & Formula in T9: =SUM(S9:S10)*25 & B9: Counter is raised by 1 if data in T9 crosses above 100 every time

Comment: What's in S10? Anyway, as far as i understand, live streamed data is a feature for Excel 365. I don't have it, so i can't really test my solution. Even so, i've edited the code. Please test it and send feedbacks.

Comment: This is not Excel 365, this streaming is being done by Some Software which is exported to Excel for Data Streaming.

Comment: is there a way i can sent u the file

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, if i send u the file, im sure you can figure this out in a moments time.

Comment: I think that would be hardly the case. The key is the software you are using for data streaming. Can you give me some details about it? Can i find it somewhere?

Comment: Its a stock prices streaming app which may not work without a user ID

Comment: I've created a new code. Try that and send feedbacks. Without the streaming app (and the file) i can't really test anything and right now i have no more ideas. Consider it my last attempt.

Comment: Is there a way I could rate your solution on this site

Comment: As the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), as questioner you can accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. If you have earned the privilege, you can also up-vote/down-vote answers and/or comments that are useful even if you are not the one that have posed the question. These methods are the best ways to say "thank you" to other users while helping future research being faster and simplier.

Comment: Just need one more help from your side, Everytime the counter is increased by one can we make Excel emit a "Beep" sound, I have one Function Module however it does not work as designed, it just keeps beeping if values remain above 100. Can we add a condition to it.

Comment: Unable to post code, giving error, link i used to get solution....https://excel.tips.net/T007658_Conditionally_Making_a_Sound.html

Comment: Would it be possible to Embed the sound code in the same Module we created for Counter?

Comment: I understand you are new to this, but we are not supposed to keep on "chatting" in the comments. One problem, one question. This beep problem is a new one. You should ask a new question (if your previous research/attempt didn't succeed). Just this time, i've edited once again the code. Try it. I presume your attempt didn't work because you didn't place the declaration of function at the top of the module. As i said: we should stop.

Comment: Getting a Compile Error: The Code in this Project must be updated for use on 64-Bit systems, Please review and update Declare Statements and then mark them with the Ptr Safe Attribute

Comment: Should I raise a new question for this?

Comment: Thanks i just just did a few modifications to the code and it has started working with the Beep.